# How to edit discord message multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

how can I edit the same message multiple times with a delay...?

Here is what i tried... :

```js
        message.channel.send(`a`)
        .then(message => {
          setTimeout( () => {
          message.edit(`ab`)
          },1000);
        })
        .then(message => {
          setTimeout( () => {
          message.edit(`abc`)
          },1000);
        })
        .then(message => {
          setTimeout( () => {
          message.edit(`abcd`)
          },1000);
        })
        .then(message => {
          setTimeout( () => {
          message.edit(`abcde`)
          },1000);
        });
```

smth like this should work, but if i try this one the error is: of course `Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined` (the error is at the "message.edit (`abc`)" part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is nothing is passed into the second `.then`

The value passed to the next `.then` is always the return value of the previous `.then`

For example:

```js
Promise.resolve('foo').then(value => {
  console.log(value)
  return 'abc'
}).then(console.log)
```

will fist log `foo` and then `abc`

The easiest solution I can think of is to increase the `setTimeout` delay by 1000 each time

```js
message.channel.send('a').then(message => {
  setTimeout(() => message.edit('ab'), 1000)
  setTimeout(() => message.edit('abc'), 2000)
  setTimeout(() => message.edit('abcd'), 3000)
  setTimeout(() => message.edit('abcde'), 4000)
})
```

If you wanted this to be more general you could do something like this:

```js
function changeMessage(delay, messages, message) {
  for(i in messages) {
    setTimeout(() => message.edit(messages[i]), delay * i)
  }
}

message.channel.send('a').then(message => changeMessage(1000, ['ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde'], message))
```

The function `changeMessage` takes in a delay time, an array of messages, and the actual message object you want to edit, and just edits the message to each new string in the array of messages every x seconds

This problem has a nice syntactic solution, but oftentimes it's easier to use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you want to run a bunch of Promises sequentially